# Em java, como fazer que só uma janela JFrame feche ao clicar no x, ao invés de todas?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Estou fazendo um programa em Java com várias janelas `JFrame`, e queria que, quando apertasse o x de uma das janelas apenas esta fechasse, ao invés de todas elas.

Comment: Considere incluir o que você está tentando fazer. Além disto, talvez o melhor, no seu caso, não seja usar várias `JFrame`, mas usar `JInternalFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

Basta utilizar a constante da classe [JFrame](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html), [DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE), no método [setDefaultCloseOperation(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation-int-), ao invés de [EXIT_ON_CLOSE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#EXIT_ON_CLOSE). Aqui está um pequeno exemplo que elaborei:

**Window.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Window extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Random RND = new Random(); 
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public Window() {
        super("Close me!");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(RND.nextInt(1024), RND.nextInt(768), 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            new Window();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Coloca na classe que extende JFrame

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```